# 「X 程度なら、いっそ Y」 sentence meaning

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, syntax

Could you help me get the meaning of this sentence? In particular I don't get the meaning of the second part. Context: a swordsman is forced to fight to a common person by his enemies, but he doesn't fight seriously because he doesn't want to harm him. At the end, the enemies kill the common person and make it look like the swordsman did it.

> ここで追いつめられて斬ってしまえる程度なら、いっそ笑って見ていてやれるものを。

My attempt: "If you're going to be cornered here and killed, I'd rather try to laugh" (?)

More context here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ekPn.jpg (I uploaded the page before and the page after too, so the page in question is the second one).
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       ( The previous answer helped me, Thanks! )
```

> ここで追いつめられて斬ってしまえる程度なら、いっそ笑って見ていてやれるものを。

( It seems ...  this [ 程度 ] is not the right word here.  This anachronistic construction is a little too advanced for the author and editor, and many readers. ) ( ***  See below )

> If you (the black haired hero) were the type who could slay the opponent (the nervous, novice kid with the white hair), then we (the 2 malicious Senpai's) would [rather] have just sat back and relished the spectacle.

[next page]

> But it's your half-assed principle and code (of conduct) that'll do you in.

---

いっそ -- ( one meaning is "rather" )

> [https://kotobank.jp/word/いっそ-434335](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9D-434335)
> ‎
> デジタル大辞泉 - いっその用語解説 - ［副］《「いっそう（一層）」の音変化という》１. 中途半端な状態を排して思いきったことを選ぶときに用いる。とやかく言わないで。むしろ。
> いっそのこと。「そんな絵なら いっそ掛けないほうがましだ」 ...........

ejje.weblio.jp/content/いっそ -- ( 都会暮らしがいやになってきた. いっそ郷里の村に帰ってみようか ==  I've got sick of city life. Shall we (take the plunge and) go back. )

This  is the most common use.  It's sightly different in the manga page.

---

.... ものを

> [https://kotobank.jp/word/ものを-646481](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%92-646481)
> ‎
> デジタル大辞泉 - ものを の用語解説 - ［接助］《「ものを」から》活用語の連体形に付く。１. 愚痴・恨み・不平・不満・反駁(はんばく) などの気持ちを込めて、逆接の確定条件を表す。...

ejje.weblio.jp/content/ものを --  ( だまっていれば いいものを. == He should have kept silent. )

だまっていれば いいものを. == If only you had kept silent. ("If only you had kept your mouth shut.")

---

( It seems ...  this [ 程度 ] is not the right word here.  This anachronistic construction is a little too advanced for the author and editor, and many readers. ) ( ***  See below )

Ok, i have a theory.   i think the more fitting word タマ was first used, and the editor didn't think it appropriate for a PG-13 mangazine, because  タマ is a gangster lingo, and has other adult overtones.  The editor couldn't think of a good replacement and got stuck with  [ 程度 ] .

不良・ヤクザ用語. 『タマ』

> 「あいつはそんなタマじゃない」と言う時の「タマ」とは何ですか? - あざけり ...
>
> detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1339904918
> ‎
> 奴』（やつ）と同じ意味です。ttp://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%82
> %BF... ... 言葉の使い方 よく使われる「あの人はそんなタマじゃない」という言葉ですが

Comment: Thank you! So, if タマ was used, it would have been something like "If you had balls to etc.", right?

Answer (score 4):

I think the important part is the sentence after what you quoted here.

> (We had to do this) because you have your own belief

which comes second in Japanese while in English, you start your sentence with this part.

So, the part you quoted should be translated like:

> We could've enjoyed watching your action if you were the type who would simply kill him with the pressure we are giving you.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! So what's the meaning of いっそ here? And what's the grammar function of を at the end of the second sentence?

Comment: @Marco perhaps this?: "いっそ　①実に。ほんとうに。まったく。" (Kōjien)

Comment: In this context, "いっそ" is very hard to translate to English, in my opinion or probably because I do not speak native-English. Anyway, You are right that typically, "いっそ" means, "rather." But in this context, I wouldn't try direct translation. What H. Ha did sounds more professional.